# How to mqtt publish on NestJS?

Tags: mqtt, nestjs

I am making mqtt client using NestJS

I used @MessagePattern to confirm the subscription. (@Ctx, @Payload information is also checked normally.)

By the way, mqtt client information is created in app.module
I tried to use MqttClient using @Inject in Controller
The following error occurs in client.push.

Help me
**(The controller's client.publish does not work.)**

[main.ts]

```
async function bootstrap() {
  /*const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  await app.listen(3000);*/

  const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>(
      AppModule,{
        transport:Transport.MQTT,
        options:{
          url : 'serverIp',
          username : 'name',
          password : 'pwd',
          port : 1883,
          protocol : 'mqtt'
        }
      },
  );

  app.listen(() =>{
    console.log('[Agent Server is Listening...]');
  })

}
bootstrap();
```

[app.module.ts]

```
@Module({
  imports: [      
    ClientsModule.register([
      {
        name: 'MQ_CLIENT',
        transport: Transport.MQTT,
        options: {
          host:'serverIp',
          port:1883,
          //protocol:'mqtt',
          username:'name',
          password:'pwd'
        }
      },
    ]),
    ConfigModule
  ],
  controllers: [AppController, VcController],
  providers: [AppService, VcService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

[Controller]

```
@Controller('vc')
export class VcController {

    constructor(
        @Inject(WINSTON_MODULE_NEST_PROVIDER) private readonly logger : LoggerService,
        @Inject('MQ_CLIENT') private client : MqttClient
    ) {}

    @MessagePattern('SomeTopic)
    private tempFunction(@Ctx() context: MqttContext, @Payload() data){
      
        this.client.publish('Publish TopicId', 'tttaaaaaa'); //The problem arises here
    }
}
```

[Error Messgae]

```
TypeError: callback is not a function
    at ClientMqtt.publish (C:\Wrok_Git\Demo\20201013_nestjsMqtt\mqtt-agent-02\node_modules\@nestjs\microservices\client\client-mqtt.js:104:13)
    at VcController.vcTest (C:\Wrok_Git\Demo\20201013_nestjsMqtt\mqtt-agent-02\dist\controller\vc\vc.controller.js:40:21)
    at C:\Wrok_Git\Demo\20201013_nestjsMqtt\mqtt-agent-02\node_modules\@nestjs\microservices\context\rpc-context-creator.js:44:33
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async C:\Wrok_Git\Demo\20201013_nestjsMqtt\mqtt-agent-02\node_modules\@nestjs\microservices\context\rpc-proxy.js:11:32
    at async ServerMqtt.handleEvent (C:\Wrok_Git\Demo\20201013_nestjsMqtt\mqtt-agent-02\node_modules\@nestjs\microservices\server\server.js:61:32)
```

Comment: Its complaining  that your `this.client.publish()` function should have a callback() function. Now why its looking for that, I don't know.....I don't see it in the code.

Comment: this.client.publish('SmartHome/02VC01/12345678', 'tttaaaaaa', function(){
            console.log("this is callback");
        })

I tested it in a form like this, but the same error occurred..

Answer (score 1):

This works for me -

```js
constructor(@Inject('MQ_CLIENT') private client: ClientProxy) {
    client.connect();
}

@MessagePattern('SomeTopic')
private tempFunction(@Ctx() context: MqttContext, @Payload() data) {
    this.client.emit('help', 'data');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a little digging and came up with the following:

https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/6403

The gist of it, you need to call `mqttClient.connect()` beforehand, but you will not find that function in the interface for it.

Answer (score -2):

The code of question is all OK.
Only replace the line
`this.client.publish('Publish TopicId', 'tttaaaaaa');`
with
`this.client.emit('Publish TopicId', 'tttaaaaaa')`

Comment: You are going to need to include a lot more context for this to be a vaild answer.

Comment: @hardillb I don't get it when I flag posts like this for "not an answer" it gets rejected. According to the standards of SO this is not a valid answer is it? There is just an unformatted code-snippet without any explanation whatsoever.